# OpenShift use Ruby without Rack

Tags: ruby, server, openshift

I am making a API project on OpenShift, which has a Node.js server and Ruby backend.  I have set up a deployment for Node.js to handle API requests and a MongoDB deployment to store the data, but I'm having trouble with the Ruby backend.

The Ruby backend is responsible for updating the database every so often and thus must run at a regular interval or constantly.  That's find, the issue is that OpenShift seems to want me to use Rack to start a web server, but that's not what I want.  I just want the Ruby to run as a daemon and scrape the web to update the API every, say, 15 minutes.

How can I use Ruby without making a webserver- that is, get around the errors about not having Rack gem installed?

Comment: You should be adding a `.s2i/bin/run` script that calls your ruby file as a daemon. Source: https://docs.openshift.com/online/creating_images/s2i.html#s2i-scripts

Comment: Adding to what @WillGordon said, ensure that the last command in override executable ``.s2i/bin/run`` script uses ``exec`` to run the command. Also see details about overriding ``run`` script in https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

Comment: Thanks! This worked (after I also wrote an assemble script to install the gems to the right location).  However, exec suppresses the output, and it doesn't write the daemon's output to the log.  Is there a way to fix this?